# How can I run await in the beforeAll function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs

I'm trying to run some async functions before any test in a specific file is ran. I tried doing the following:

```
describe('api/user', () => {
    let user;
    const userObj = {...};

    beforeAll(async () => {
        user = await new User(userObj).save(); // This is a mongoose document
    });
    ...
});
```

Whenever I have something in the `beforeAll` function I get an error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

I tried changing the timeout time to 30 seconds and that didn't fix it. I then tried adding the `done` function before the end of the `beforeAll` function, and it didn't fix the issue either.

How can I run `await` in the `beforeAll` function?

Comment: Can you create a new test file and try to reproduce the problem? I believe the second argument `timeout` of the `beforeAll` function works.

Comment: Try not using async/await and instead use `then` and return the promise

Comment: Your `new User().save()` code is probably not runs.

Comment: What's User? Is it Mongoose or else? This needs to be specified in the question. The question doesn't make sense in general because in general it's supposed to be done like you did and it's expected to work.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, it's a mongodb doc

Comment: @felixmosh When I put the same code in a test function, it works correctly

Comment: Mongo or Mongoose? Mongoose is known for producing pending errors if there's no connection. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem as it's specific to your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask Mongoose

Comment: Then it's most likely db connection wasn't established. This is a known Mongoose thing.

Comment: @EstusFlask YES! That's what it was! `server = require('../../index');` was in the `beforeEach` function which I guess ran after `beforeAll`. So I copied it over to `beforeAll` as well. Thanks! Can you post as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was that simple. I'm sure it's a dupe question as it was discussed multiple times on SO but cannot find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That a block with `async` function results in test timeout even with very long timeout values means that there's pending promise that never resolves. Adding `done` to `async` functions is not a viable option because it cannot improve this but can also result in more timeouts in case `done` is never called.

This is a known case for Mongoose models, it's known for chaining connection promise internally. If there's no connection, model operations return pending promises.

The solution is to establish a connection before other operations. In case a connection is shared for the test suite, it should be:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(...);
    user = await new User(userObj).save();
});
```

Comment: And I have a side question, is there any reason why `server = require('../../index');` should be in the `beforeEach` function, or would it be okay to have it just in the `beforeAll` function

Comment: Usually modules are imported at top level, i.e. outside beforeAll. It makes sense to import it in beforeEach if you have a reason to re-import it for each test, e.g. together with `jest.resetModules()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and had to explicitly pass in and call the `done` function:

```js
describe('api/user', () => {
    let user;
    const userObj = {...};

    beforeAll(async (done) => {
        user = await new User(userObj).save(); // This is a mongodb document
        done();
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: `async` shouldn't be used with `done`. This is usually a sign that devs don't know how async testing works in Jest. It isn't supposed to help with a timeout in this case. Quite the opposite, it will surely time out when it fails because `done` is never reached.

Comment: Thanks, @Estus.  Makes sense.  I'll have to revisit my code with that in mind, as it does actually work in my case, no doubt because I'm doing something else wrong.